# perl Excel::Writer::XLSX generates outline that is offset by 1 row

Tags: perl, excel-writer-xlsx

I am trying to build a spreadsheet with outlined rows using perl module Excel::Writer::XLSX. I need the row outline symbol to appear above the outline level bar. When I run the script below, the outline symbols and level bars are correctly generated, but shifted down one row.

```
use strict;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $visible = 1;
my $symbols_below = 0;
my $symbols_right = 0;
my $auto_style = 0;

my $output_rpt = 'report.xlsx';
my $color1 = "#CBBEA0";
my $color2 = "#DDD7C5";

my $workbook   = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $output_rpt );
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet( 'report' );
$worksheet1->outline_settings($visible, $symbols_below, $symbols_right, $auto_style);

my $format1  = $workbook->add_format( bold => 1, bg_color => $color1, align => 'center' );
my $format2  = $workbook->add_format( bold => 1, bg_color => $color1, align => 'left'  );
my $format3  = $workbook->add_format( bold => 1, bg_color => $color2, align =>'left'  );
my $format4  = $workbook->add_format( align => 'center'  );

my @last = qw( Smith Jones Panglossian );
my @first = qw( Algonquin Mephibosheth Noah );
my @age = (24, 42, 962);
my @hidden    = (0, 0, 0);
my @level     = (0, 1, 1);
my @collapsed = (1, 0, 0);

for my $idx (0..2) {
    my $row = $idx+1;
    $worksheet1->set_row( $row, undef, undef, $hidden[$idx], $level[$idx], 
$collapsed[$idx] );
$worksheet1->write( 'A' . $row, $first[$idx], $format2);
$worksheet1->write( 'B' . $row, $last[$idx], $format3);
$worksheet1->write( 'C' . $row, $age[$idx], $format4);
}
$workbook->close();
```

The output spreadsheet is in the image below. Note that the outline bar is offset by 1 row

[image: output spreadsheet]

Comment: In the code:  The collapse symbol is placed in row 1.and the outline bar is set to span rows 2 and 3. .In the resulting spreadsheet: The  collapse symbol is in row 2 (one row below where I put it, row 1).  the outline bar spans rows 3 and 4. (also 1 row below the span of 2 and 3). The outline bar is spanning a row that was never even mentioned in the code (row 4)

Comment: My question is: What am I missing to make the outline span the rows that I want it to span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) documentation for the [`set_row`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#set_row(-$row,-$height,-$format,-$hidden,-$level,-$collapsed-)) method, you will see:

```
$worksheet->set_row( 0, 20 );    # Row 1 height set to 20
```

Which means that the index is 0-based, but you are giving it `$idx+1`. Change that line into the following and it should work as you expect (it worked for me when I tested it on my end):

```
$worksheet1->set_row( $idx, undef, undef, $hidden[$idx], $level[$idx], $collapsed[$idx] );
#                      ^^^
```

(There does appear to be a mistake a little later on in the documentation, where one of the examples shows a 1-based index. [Issue reported.](https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/pull/204))